# How to use fluent nhibernate to map a value type collection?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

.........

```
<property name="Title" />

<set name ="Contacts" lazy="false" table ="Ad_Contacts">
  <key column="Ad_Id"></key>
  <element type ="String" column="Contact" not-null="true"></element>
</set>
```

.........

**HasMany(x => x.Contacts).AsSet()** , which is the statement I used for fluent nhibernate mapping. It doesn't work. Contacts is a collection of string.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? If so, please point to it and mark this as answered. I'm stuck on the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the following map:

```
HasMany<string>(x => x.Contacts).AsElement("Ad_Id");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HasMany(x => x.Contacts).AsSet().KeyColumn("Ad_Id").Element("Contact");
```